# How to fix 'URISyntaxException' while coping a file in hdfs

Tags: hadoop

"hadoop fs -copyFromLocal [-f] C:\Users\Divya\Downloads\ml-100k\u.data mydir"
this the command i am using. What's the problem in it?

Answer (score 0):

The `[-f]` isn't the proper syntax. It's just `-f` if you are forcing a file copy

And you will want to make sure `mydir` already exists